What is considered as "2 FMAs"?

The Intel® Xeon® Silver 4216 processor installed in the node supports the AVX-512 instruction set. When using AVX-512, how many FP32 operations can one core execute per clock cycle?
Hint: Consider the number of AVX-512 instructions executed per clock cycle and the number of FP32 operations per AVX-512 instruction.

When I looked up the specifications, I found the following:

Instruction set extensions: Intel® SSE4.2, Intel® AVX, Intel® AVX2, Intel® AVX-512
Number of AVX-512 FMA units: 1
Intel® Advanced Vector Extensions 512 (AVX-512), new instruction set extensions, delivering ultra-wide (512-bit) vector operations capabilities, with up to 2 FMAs (Fused Multiply Add instructions), to accelerate performance for your most demanding computational tasks.

I understand that AVX-512 can process 512/32 = 16 FP32 elements, but I'm not sure about how to interpret the phrase "two FMAs" - should I think of this as 2 additions and 2 multiplications, or should I just think of it as 2 operations(either addition or multiplication)?

1 FMA is considered 2 FLOPs, but in terms of the hardware it's one operation, costing the same as a mul or add/sub.  (Any of those are 1 uop for the pipeline for scalar or any vector width, in Intel CPUs other than low-power (E-core)).  Except for the performance counters like fp_arith_inst_retired.256b_packed_single which double-count FMA instructions, so they're actually FLOP counters not instruction counters.

should I think of this as 2 additions and 2 multiplications, No, although it's close to the same result but without rounding the product before doing the add.  or should I just think of it as 2 operations(either addition or multiplication)? no, unless you're using it with a multiplier like 1.0 or an addend like 0.0 for some reason.  Have you read a definition of FMA, like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation or is there some other reason for wondering this?

What conclusions are you hoping to draw from an answer to this?  Do you want to know the performance cost of add or mul ops that aren't part of an FMA, on the same Intel CPU?  (They cost the same as an FMA, identical throughput, execution port choice, and latency)
